# how to show identity column value in text box

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How to show identity column value in text box in asp.net page. I found this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An explicit value for the identity
>   column in table 'Doctors_Record' can only be specified when a column
>   list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON...

Comment: Do you use SQLDataSource control? If yes, show it. Or show your code where you inserting and updating records in database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to insert a value into a column that was set as `IDENTITY`. You should omit this `IDENTITY` column from the columns list in the `INSERT` statement.

Otherwise, if you are trying to do that, insert an explicit value to that column, then you have to turn the [**`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) `ON`:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Doctors_Record ON;

-- Then do `INSERT`.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Doctors_Record OFF;
```

---

To get the last identity value inserted, use Use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28v=sql.100%29.aspx):

```
-- do insert

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Comment: i have done it but i want to show identity value in text box of asp.net page.what is the code for it..??